# C# Type inference: How to properly define constraints on method?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Hi I am having hard time making C# type inference do what I want. I have a very specific situation where I have a lot of variables in the flavor of

```
ConcurrentDictionary<T, IDictionary<U, V> >
```

where T,U,V can be some random types like long, int or whatever.

I want to write the method that works with this types of variables - notably examines their histograms.

So I have written a method

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetDictionaryHistogram<T, U, V, W>(T dictionary) where T : ConcurrentDictionary<U, IDictionary<V, W>>
{
    return dictionary.Select(p => p.Value.Count)
                     .GroupBy(p => p)
                     .Select(p => new Tuple<int, int>(p.Key, p.Count()))
                     .OrderBy(p => p.Item1);
}
```

But when I try to call it, C# gives me an error that it cannot infer the types.
For example on a variable of type

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int,IDictionary<int, int> > foo;
```

I get the error:

> Error 118 The type arguments for method
>   'Auditor.AuditorHelpers.GetDictionaryHistogram(T)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics: Why can't the compiler infer the type arguments in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968834/generics-why-cant-the-compiler-infer-the-type-arguments-in-this-case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type inference infers from *arguments* to *formal parameter types*. No inferences are ever made on *constraints* because constraints are not a part of the *signature* of a method.

In your case type inference must always fail; type inference cannot possibly infer types for U and V because they do not appear in a formal parameter type.

For about a dozen people telling me that I am wrong to believe that this rule is sensible, see the comments to [my article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Comment: I've read that blog post, but I'm confused by your example.  What constraint would be violated by passing `null` to a parameter of type `C<Iguana>`?  While I recognize that applying type constraints which are defined in terms of other type constraints could yield ambiguous situations, especially with interfaces, it would seem that it should be possible to consider inheritance constraints as well as `class` and `struct` to be part of a signature.

Comment: Tahnk You Eric. I corrected myself like people suggest in answers but I could not fathom WHAT THE HELL?. And I have read your post on this subject so I should know better:) I think the error message could be a little better in this case so I would not frantically trying to improve the types in the definition:D Clearly U,V,W are not part of method signature so this should fail! Hail to the expert:)

Comment: @supercat: The constraint violated would be the constraint that T is Mammal.

Answer (score 2):

The type parameter `T` is unnecessary. You should just write

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetDictionaryHistogram<U, V, W>(
    ConcurrentDictionary<U, IDictionary<V, W>> dictionary)
```

and it should work fine.

Your type of constraint, where a parameter must be of a certain type, is useful only in a few situations. The most common one is to avoid boxing of value types that implement an interface. Compare these two methods:

```
public static DoSomething(ISomeInterface thing) {}
public static DoSomething<T>(T thing) where T : ISomeInterface {}
```

When the first method is called with a value type argument, the argument is boxed and cast to the interface type.

When the second method is called with a value type, the generic type parameter is replaced with the value type and no boxing takes place.

Comment: Also, it could be useful if you wanted to retain the type T as part of the return value, which is not the case here.  But I agree that in this case omitting T and using the constraint as the type parameters is the way to go and will allow the compiler to infer all three of the other types.

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is saying that it can't figure out the dependencies between your types.

Try doing:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetDictionaryHistogram<U, V, W>(ConcurrentDictionary<U, IDictionary<V, W>> dictionary)
{
    return dictionary.Select(p => p.Value.Count)
                     .GroupBy(p => p)
                     .Select(p => new Tuple<int, int>(p.Key, p.Count()))
                     .OrderBy(p => p.Item1);
}
```