# Accessing nested generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Supposed I have some code like so:

```
// This represents some query that will return type T when executed.
public interface IQuery<T> { }

// An example query that returns bool
public class MyQuery : IQuery<bool> { }

// A separate class that's actually responsible for executing the queries.
public class Executor {
    public T Execute<T>(IQuery<T> query)
}

// Usage
executor.Execute(new MyQuery()) // => true/false
```

No problems so far. But say I want to change my executor class such that it's responsible for instantiation of queries. Ideally I'd like usage to be something like:

```
// Usage
executor.Execute<MyQuery>() // => true/false
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to model this method signature. The closest I can get is:

```
public T Execute<TQuery, T>() where TQuery : IQuery<T>
```

The problem with this signature is that it requires all of the type parameters to be explicitly specified. There is no way for `T` to be inferred from `TQuery` since the generic type constraints are not considered when inferring type parameters.

So far the only workaround I've found is to set up a dummy argument to help with inference from the formal parameters. Basically going back to the original example but instead of passing an actual instance using `new MyQuery()` I can pass something like `default(MyQuery)`. This is clunky though and the makes the API not at all obvious.

Is there some workaround that I'm missing?

Comment: Try this: `where TQuery : IQuery<T>, new()` but note that the fact that you have 2 generic parameters will mean you need to specify two generic arguments as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics: Why can't the compiler infer the type arguments in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968834/generics-why-cant-the-compiler-infer-the-type-arguments-in-this-case)