# Type arguments can't be inferred: why?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

The following c# code can't be inferred.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Pipeline<string[]> s = null;

            // Compiles fine.
            s.WithNewDelimiters<Pipeline<string[]>, string[], string>();

            // Fails to compile.
            s.WithNewDelimiters();
        }
    }

    public class Pipeline<T> { }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void WithNewDelimiters<TPipeline, TEnumerable, TElement>
            (this TPipeline pipeline)
            where TPipeline : Pipeline<TEnumerable>
            where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TElement>
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Although the reason why this is a generic extension method isn't important, it's so that I can chain With-ers like this on any instance of `Pipeline<T>`

Now that's out of the way, here's my logic: I'm reading from left-to-right, so potentially this is not the algorithmic way that the C# compiler works.

- First, look at `TPipeline`. `TPipeline` is a `Pipeline<TEnumerable>` We've passed in a `Pipeline<string[]>`. This means that `TEnumerable == string[]`
- Next, look at `TEnumerable`. `TEnumerable` is a `IEnumerable<string>`
- Since `TElement` is unconstrained, it can be anything, so it can be set to `string`.

Obviously this logic is either flawed or not how the C# compiler works. I think I've gone wrong by assuming that the value of one constraint affects another.

But I'm still not sure why this is ambiguous to the C# compiler. There is no other configuration of type parameters that could satisfy the requirements here, surely?

Comment: I don't think _constraints_ are anyhow used to infer the type arguments. They are only applied _after_ the type arguments have been inferred to check if the result is valid.

Comment: Take a look to your right, and rifle through some of the many questions on type inference, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968834). One of them is bound to clear things up.

Comment: Eric Lippert explains: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/